# MySQL query -> using time to alter an int value and sort it

Tags: mysql, date, time

I'm making a multiplayer highscore table to a game. Scores should decrease by 1 point per hour. Is it possible to make a query that calculates how many hours passed since last time a score was submitted by using a timestamp and an integer? I've looked at TIME_TO_SEC() but how do I combine that function with the score-column?

In a common language this is something I'd like to do:

```
float getScore(int timePassedInSeconds, float score)
{
   return score-((float)timePassedInSeconds/3600.0f);
}
```

And then sort the table based on what that function returns...

Comment: Maybe try [`TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, colval, NOW())`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff).

Answer (score 0):

make an UNSIGNED INT last_modified column (you can make it a TIMESTAMP but that makes arithmetic operations a little confusing).

```
CREATE TABLE scores( score FLOAT, last_modified INT UNSIGNED, ... );
```

and do your update operations like this:

```
UPDATE scores SET 
   score = score - ( ( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() - last_modified ) / 3600.0 ),
   last_modified = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() ...
```